# Flutter Web crash in IOS mobile if greater than version of IOS 15

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am developing one website in flutter web and that crash randomly in IOS device if device version is greater than 15. I am investing more time in that and i can't find any proper solution.

I have checked my way with different different way like clear cache and controller delete and many way.